# Is the Blood Fury Tattoo's damage doubled on a critical hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, critical-hit

The question is as the title says, is the 4d6 necrotic damage doubled if you critted the attack that you then use the item's ability on. The item text in question is below.

> When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can expend a charge to deal an extra 4d6 necrotic damage to the target, and you regain a number of hit points equal to the necrotic damage dealt.

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate because I felt it has effectively been answered before (this isn't a bad thing by the way). The Blood Fury Tattoo explicitly stated that its damage is "extra" and the Q&A I linked to has answers stating that any "extra" damage is doubled on a critical hit. If you think there's some nuance or something that makes the Blood Fury Tattoo exceptional and not answered there, feel free to [edit] the post or leave a comment explaining why. Your question can always be reopened